# Convert PNG image to Base64

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I am converting drawable resource png image to bitmap and then converting that bitmap to base64 and sending it to server by web service.

The image is stored on server at some address and in response i am getting URL where the image is stored.

The problem is after sending image to server the url which i am getting with that url i am setting image to other imageview but the transperent part of image is becoming black colored,
i think the problem is with converting png image to base64,

my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, false);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bao);
byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

please give me solution ASAP

Comment: The problem is probably in how you are decoding the bitmap. You need to add options to maintain the alpha channel.

Comment: @dcharms : can you give me example code

Comment: Can you post your code for when you are downloading and decoding the image from Base64? It would be easier to give an example if I knew how you were attempting it right now.

Comment: it is stored on server and i am getting the url(e.g www.test.com/demo.png) only, from url i am downloading image using universal image loader

Comment: And how are you decoding it on the server?

Comment: at server side php developer is using the following inbuilt function of php,
**base64_decode($img)**

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are doing seems right. Depending on the version of Android you are compiling with, `decodeResource` can have different default behavior. You can force the `BitmapFactory` to use an alpha channel when decoding with the following code.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this also not working for me, do you have any other solution?

Comment: If you view the server image in a browser is it black?

Comment: That means it uploaded correctly and is not the Base64. Post your code that downloads it.

Comment: i am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: You need to post the actual code if I'm going to have any chance of helping you. The documentation says alpha is supported by default, but you may have inadvertently disabled it in options you applied.